# How to link redmine user with repository user

Tags: git, repository, redmine

I have a Redmine project linked with a repository (git).
I want to link my commits with my Redmine account. Now my every commit is made by "Anonymous" user, because RM username and repo username differ.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under your project settings, in the Repository tab below the greyed out section with your repo URL, there is an icon for users. This screen will allow you to map repo usernames with redmine usernames. This is present in my redmine version 1.1.3.stable. Not sure what version it was implemented in.

Comment: yup, this one works best ^_^ I'm not sure, if I could use it earlier, because now I'm using stable 1.2.0 (released week ago ;)). Anyway, thank you for this solution.

Comment: In 1.2.1, this should now automatic if the git username or e-mail matches.  In the same section/tab user562034 mentions: 'Users with the same Redmine and repository username or email are automatically mapped.'

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case anymore. I cannot see such a screen in version 3.4.3

Answer (score 1):

Do you see messages [like those](http://pastebin.com/aHHdYUfM)?

```
Redmine is checking your changes for correctness...
Authenticated as Lukasz Dywicki
Changes:
    Ref: refs/heads/fusion type: commit
            Error: Initial commit can be done only by repository manager
        Commit: 442155e0797c4f4fbae74f91265ab664f3ca0880
        Commit: c8a137d577f2033721c9d52e0907b7e9f8ca48b2
            Error: Commit author name or email is wrong
            Error:     Execute following commands and _recreate_ commit:
            Error:     git config --global user.name "Lukasz Dywicki"
            Error:     git config --global user.email luke@code-house.org
```

As describes in [this thread](http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/22692?r=23334#message-23334):

> Remember that your email in `~/.gitconfig` file should match the one you are registered with in Redmine:
>   To check your email:

```
git config --get user.email
```

> To set your email:

```
locally (in project folder):
git config user.email your@email.com

or globally (anywhere):
git config --global user.email your@email.com
```

> that's because of a logic (problem?) in a redmine code..

Comment: Witaj ;)
No i don't see those messages. RM works fine with my repo. Only "bug" is that commits are not mine.
So you're telling that user is identified by email address ... eh, ok, so i'll have to change mail adressess in my local repos ;)
Thanks, i'll check your solution later and mark it as answer if correct

Comment: So... I've found my name here ;)

Comment: @splatch indeed :) Let me know if that is an issue, and if you want me to obfuscate it.

Comment: My name is fine, please just ommit project name.